# Can't connect to wifi (with username, password and proxy with port)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I can connect normally to my school's WiFi from my phone, and my friends can connect to it from their "non Windows 10" laptops (working with Windows 7),

Wen I try to connect from my laptop (I have a message (instantly after trying to connect) error like "unable to connect to WiFi" or something like that, just translated it from french).

I tried everything (and restarted the system after each attempt):

- installing Windows 7 and 8's drivers,
- typing some cmd commands `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int IP reset`

Here are some screenshots:

[image: proxy configuration]
[image: username and password]